# Unable to read Firestore document using Javascript(VueJS)

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, google-cloud-firestore

I keep getting the error below when I try to read a document data. The weird thing is that I can read the documentID and I can also write to firestore. 
Below is how I am reading the data:

```
async fetchUserDetailByID(context, userID) {
            try{
                let tmp = {};
                await userRef.doc(userID).get().then((doc)=> {
                    console.log(doc.data())
                });
                return tmp
            }catch (e) {
                console.log(e);
            }
        }
```

Below is the error I am getting:

> FirebaseError: Function GeoPoint() requires its first argument to be
>   of type number, but it was: undefined

PS: My firestore rule allows read and write by anyone

Comment: Scratch that, you should check that `userID` is a number. It's undefined so your call to `fetchUserDetailByID` is the issue, need to add type checking preferably in the method.

Comment: What is `userRef`? Also, the error with `GeoPoint()` does not seem to be related to your code. Are they other parts of the code implied in this problem?

Comment: @RenaudTarnec Here is the user ref 
firebase.firestore().collection('users')

Comment: @calistus ok, thanks. It doe snot explain why you get the error with GeoPoint(), which does not seem to be related to your code.

Comment: Thanks guys, I just noticed that I used 0,0 to saved default user location on my Firestore. I tried changing the value to another number other than 0,0 and it works

Answer (score 0):

I just noticed the issue cause of the issue.

It seems Firestore does not support 0 as a latitude or longitude as it's geopoint data type. 
[image]
When I changed the values of the user location, the query now works normally